# What is the true positive rate when the false positive rate is 0.5 in the model?

Tags: r, roc

I'm trying to understand how to calculate true positive rate when the FPR is 0.5 in the model and then produce ROc curves. But I'm definitely stuck with some issues in coding...

```
> library(nycflights13)
> late_arrival<- flights$arr_delay>50
> summary(late_arrival)
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical  275847   51499    9430 
> late_arrival.lr <- glm(late_arrival~carrier+dep_delay+month+year, data=flights, family='binomial')
```

Warning message:
`glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred`

```
> summary(late_arrival.lr)
Call:
glm(formula = late_arrival ~ carrier + dep_delay + month + year, 
    family = "binomial", data = flights)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.0972  -0.2445  -0.1920  -0.1570   3.9217  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -3.9122786  0.0430834 -90.807  < 2e-16 ***
carrierAA    0.2174443  0.0485813   4.476 7.61e-06 ***
carrierAS   -0.3549507  0.2540636  -1.397  0.16239    
carrierB6    0.5142442  0.0428985  11.987  < 2e-16 ***
carrierDL    0.2228855  0.0449833   4.955 7.24e-07 ***
carrierEV    0.3230899  0.0431394   7.489 6.92e-14 ***
carrierF9    1.1544420  0.1444764   7.991 1.34e-15 ***
carrierFL    0.7190162  0.0812251   8.852  < 2e-16 ***
carrierHA   -0.2276957  0.4115495  -0.553  0.58008    
carrierMQ    0.8086500  0.0475393  17.010  < 2e-16 ***
carrierOO    1.0138755  0.9037621   1.122  0.26193    
carrierUA    0.0919203  0.0431571   2.130  0.03318 *  
carrierUS    0.6063731  0.0525429  11.541  < 2e-16 ***
carrierVX   -0.0485832  0.0852892  -0.570  0.56893    
carrierWN   -0.1551747  0.0574042  -2.703  0.00687 ** 
carrierYV    0.5737826  0.1999578   2.870  0.00411 ** 
dep_delay    0.1000536  0.0004308 232.263  < 2e-16 ***
month        0.0009126  0.0024337   0.375  0.70767    
year                NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 284924  on 327345  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 108708  on 327328  degrees of freedom
AIC: 108744

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

it keeps showing me this warning:`(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)`

How do I actually come to predict conditions from here?
I know I have to produce somehow prediction and actual values to be able to come into the true positive rate. Anyone can guide me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop `year` from your model since it has no variation, re-fit the model and then pass `flights` as the `newdata` argument to the model's `predict()` method.

Example, using terms and abbreviations from Wikipedia's page on the [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic):

```r
library(nycflights13)

late_arrival<- flights$arr_delay>50
late_arrival.lr <- glm(late_arrival~carrier+dep_delay+month, data=flights, family='binomial')
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
fit <- predict(late_arrival.lr, newdata = flights, type = "response")

d <- data.frame(late_arrival, fit)

# "Confusion matrix" of actual vs predicted outcomes
# for a cutpoint of 0.5:
xtabs(~ late_arrival + I(fit > 0.5), data = d)
#>             I(fit > 0.5)
#> late_arrival  FALSE   TRUE
#>        FALSE 290637   3091
#>        TRUE    7386  26232

# Now do this for a range of cutpoints.
# Sensitivity = true positive rate = TPR
# Specificity = true negative rate = TNR
# 1 - Specificity = false positive rate = FPR = 1 - TNR
# The ROC plot is
#     x = 1 - Specificity = FPR
#     y = Sensitivity     = TPR

fun <- function(cutpoint) {
    pred <- d$fit > cutpoint
    # cm = "confusion matrix"
    cm <- xtabs(~ late_arrival + I(fit > cutpoint), data = d)
    cm <- as.list(cm)
    names(cm) <- c("TN", "FN", "FP", "TP")
    sens <- with(cm, TP / (TP + FN))
    spec <- with(cm, TN / (TN + FP))
    return(data.frame(cutpoint, sens, spec))
}

# Example output:
fun(0.5)
#>   cutpoint      sens      spec
#> 1      0.5 0.7802963 0.9894767

cutpoints <- seq(0.02, 0.98, by = 0.02)
# This does
# rbind(fun(cutpoints[1]), fun(cutpoints[2], ...)
roc <- do.call(rbind, lapply(cutpoints, fun))
plot(1 - roc$spec, roc$sens, type = "b",
     xlab = "False positive rate (1 - specificity)", 
     ylab = "True positive rate (sensitivity)",
     xlim = c(0, 1),
     ylim = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Note that a couple of issues needed to be addressed before answering your main question:

**The effect of `year` in your example is estimated to `NA` because there is no variation in this variable**, so it's impossible to estimate an effect of it.

```r
> unique(flights$year)
[1] 2013
```

If you drop this predictor and re-fit, the output makes sense (meaning that there are no NAs or enormous standard errors):

```r
> late_arrival.lr <- glm(late_arrival~carrier+dep_delay+month, data=flights, family='binomial')
Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
> coef(summary(late_arrival.lr))
                Estimate   Std. Error     z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -5.325540101 0.0564526220 -94.3364527 0.000000e+00
carrierAA    0.335139676 0.0622536491   5.3834543 7.306979e-08
carrierAS   -0.980666348 0.3701250164  -2.6495544 8.059801e-03
carrierB6    0.524971196 0.0542918253   9.6694335 4.066226e-22
carrierDL    0.406813418 0.0576767561   7.0533339 1.746810e-12
carrierEV    0.350366432 0.0535144496   6.5471370 5.865056e-11
carrierF9    0.776012126 0.2084826127   3.7221911 1.975015e-04
carrierFL    0.773647203 0.1077982499   7.1768067 7.135846e-13
carrierHA   -2.225896541 0.8684691013  -2.5630118 1.037685e-02
carrierMQ    0.847415433 0.0601677914  14.0842037 4.749822e-45
carrierOO    0.232324503 1.3043323784   0.1781176 8.586307e-01
carrierUA    0.157191477 0.0549977051   2.8581461 4.261241e-03
carrierUS    0.649304471 0.0697493204   9.3091154 1.289014e-20
carrierVX    0.237994726 0.1131585684   2.1031967 3.544858e-02
carrierWN    0.032542799 0.0736491439   0.4418626 6.585887e-01
carrierYV    0.861814625 0.2373042135   3.6316870 2.815745e-04
dep_delay    0.089655081 0.0004428296 202.4595603 0.000000e+00
month        0.005089147 0.0032449949   1.5683066 1.168096e-01
```

**The warning `fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred` often means that the outcome is perfectly predicted by one of your continuous-valued predictors**. For example:

```r
> x <- c(1, 2, 3)
> y <- c(0, 0, 1)
> coef(summary(glm(y ~ x, family="binomial")))
Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
              Estimate Std. Error       z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -115.57626  226884.08 -0.0005094067 0.9995936
x             46.34447   94156.73  0.0004922056 0.9996073
```

Here, the best estimate is

P(y = 1) = (0 if x < threshold) else 1

but this raises two numerical problems:

- The usually [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) curve of P(y = 1) vs x now ought to be a [step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). This requires an infinitely steep sigmoid, so the "slope" with respect to x tends to infinity.
- Any threshold between 2 and 3 will work equally well, so it's impossible to identify one best estimate for the intercept.

**In the `flights` case, however, I think the warning just means what it says**: Some predictions are so certain that any nuances are lost in roundoff error.

In checking whether `late_arrival` could indeed be perfectly predicted by one x variable, I used the following code:

```r
# Make warnings print as they appear.
# options() returns the previous settings, and we store it
warn <- options(warn = 1)$warn
for (i in c("carrier", "dep_delay", "month", "year")) {
  print(i)
  glm(late_arrival~flights[[i]], family='binomial')
}
# Restore the previous warning setting
options(warn = warn)
```

which prints

```r
[1] "carrier"
[1] "dep_delay"
Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
[1] "month"
[1] "year"
```

But `plot(flights$dep_delay, late_arrival)` (takes a few seconds) shows that there is in fact no complete separation where all `late_arrival` happen for `dep_delay` > some threshold.

Comment: Thank you so much.
But i need to see from this data TPR when the FPR is 0.5 in the model of : late_arrival~carrier+dep_delay+month, as well as to produce ROC curve, not simply the plot model. Can you give me a clue regarding it?